# C++ Versions, do they auto-detect the version of an exe?

Tags: c++, versions

Okay so I know that there are multiple c++ versions. And I dont really know much about the differences between them but my question is:
Lets say i made a c++ application in c++ 11 and sent it off to another computer would it come up with errors from other versions of c++ or will it automatically detect it and run with that version? 
Or am I getting this wrong and is it defined at compile time? Someone please tell me because I am yet to find a single answer to my question on google.

Comment: the application is compiled and standalone. You don't need c++ to run a c++-compiled program, unlike java or python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if you copy the source code to the other machine, and compile it there, or if you compile it on your machine and send the resulting binary to the other computer.

C++ is translated by the compiler to machine code, which runs directly on the processor. Any computer with a compatible processor will understand the machine code, but there is more than that. The program needs to interface with a filesystem, graphic adapters, and so on. This part is typically handled by the operating system, in different ways of course. Even if some of this is abstracted by C++ libraries, the calls to the operating system are different, and specific to it.

A compiled binary for ubuntu will not run on windows, for example, even if both computers have the same processor and hardware.

If you copy the source code to the other machine, and compile it there (or use a cross-compiler), your program should compile and run fine, if you don't use OS-specific features.

The C++ version does matter for compilation, you need a C++11 capable compiler of course if you have C++11 source code, but once the program is compiled, it does not matter any more.

Comment: Nothing. Really, I just asked myself why it caught that downvote before hitting the upvote button myself :-)

Answer (score 3):

C++ is compiled to machine code, which is then runnable on any computer having that architecture e.g. i386 or x64 (putting processor features like SSE etc. aside).

For Java, to bring a counterexample, it is different. There the code is compiled to a bytecode format, that is machine independent. This bytecodeformat is read/understood by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). The JVM then has to be available for your architecture and the correct version has to be installed.

Comment: There are also differences in the OS's that can break things: The ABI of the standard C library, for instance. That's why you cannot just take a linux executable and run it on a Windows machine, even though that machine might even run on the exact same hardware. You have to at least narrow the scope to machines that understand the same executable format.

Comment: That is only true if you are compiling on a specific OS, for that OS. However there are other ways of getting code into memory. You can write bootloaders, bioses, firmwares, OSes and so on. Once code gets loaded, it can be run, regardless of which C++ version.

Comment: @Espen However, such code does not have access to the standard C library, and by consequence to all parts of the standard C++ library that rely on the standard C library. Stuff like file I/O, threads, and `malloc()` is not easy to implement without relying on a kernel. So, while it's certainly possible to write such code out of pure necessity (kernels must be written in *some* language), one can argue that it's not really C/C++ code: It must be written using certain subsets of the languages, and at that level, it must usually include bits of assembler, moving it quite far from standard C/C++.

Comment: well I view the standard libraries as provided frameworks, and not part of the C language itself. You can write whatever you want in C/C++ without standard libraries, and without touching assembly. It will be low level, but you do not have to leave your language, this is true for any native language like Pascal, C, C++, and so on. I have written my share of C/C++ without the need for kernels, bios and bootloaders. It certainly is not only possible, but it is done by many people. In my demo-scene days I would have gotten a big slap in my face for loading any standard libraries :)

Answer (score 3):

> Or am I getting this wrong and is it defined at compile time?

This is precisely the idea: The code is compiled, and after that the language version is almost irrelevant. The only possible pitfall would be if a newer C++ version would include a breaking change to the standard C++ library (the library, not the language itself!). However, since the vast majority of that library is template code, it's compiled along with your own code anyway. It's basically baked into your `.exe` file along with your own code, so it's just as portable as yours. Also, both the C and C++ designers take great care *not* to break old code; so you can expect even those parts that are provided by the system itself (the standard C library) not to break anything.

So, even though there are things that could break in theory, pure C++ code should run fine on all machines that understand the same `.exe` format as the machine it was compiled on.